# Joomla Web links with subcategories not showing

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I´m using Joomla! 3.1.1(but I guess 2.5 is the same)

I created some weblinks in subcategories for example

```
Category 1
-Category 1.1 -> Web_link_1 , Web_link_2
-Category 1.2 -> Web_link_3 , Web_link_4
Category 2
-Category 2.1 -> Web_link_5 , Web_link_6
-Category 2.1 -> Web_link_7 , Web_link_8
```

When I use the "module weblinks" to show my top hint, I only can select one of the subcategories but if I choose Category 1 for example the extension is not navigating between subcategories.

What could I do? Is that difficult to change in the default core module? (I tried by myself but I´m not a php expert).

TIA.

Comment: First of all exactly what version are you on? In the 3 series you should be on at least 3.1.5 as their is a serious security flaw in all previous versions, not to mention lots of changes and bug fixes since the original 3.0 release.

Comment: I´m currently using Joomla! 3.1.1 Stable

Comment: You need to update to 3.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weblinks module is not helpful in this case, I usually chose to create a separate page with menu-link (here you have an option to show all categories).

If you like to use a module, you could look at some free extensions unfortunately most are not ported to 3.0 yet. However this one seems to do what you like:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/weblinks/21303?qh=YToyOntpOjA7czo3OiJ3ZWJsaW5rIjtpOjE7czo4OiJ3ZWJsaW5rcyI7fQ%3D%3D

Comment: Could you be a little more specific what you would like to get? Would you like like to list all weblinks starting from Root? Would you like to see the hierarchy (the weblinks module doesn't do that, it just gives a flat list)? Maybe you would like both?